# Adding x axis string value in a chart instead of number

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, mschart

I'm trying to design a chart where x represents the exception message and y represents how many time it occurred.

I'm not able to show x value (exception message) under each bar, I also tried labelling x and having range for each label but the bars are not generated over this label but away from them.

Here an example of my code

```
 reportChart.Series.Add(exception);
 reportChart.Series[exception].SetDefault(true);
 reportChart.Series[exception].Enabled = true;
 reportChart.Series[exception].Points.AddXY(exception,ExceptionMessages[exception]);
```

`ExceptionMessages[exception]` is a dictionary that contains the value of how many times the current exception occurred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> ExceptionMessages = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        ExceptionMessages.Add("Exception 1", 20);
        ExceptionMessages.Add("Exception 2", 50);
        ExceptionMessages.Add("Exception 3", 30);
        ExceptionMessages.Add("Exception 4", 60);
        ExceptionMessages.Add("Exception 5", 10);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> exception in ExceptionMessages)
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(exception.Key, exception.Value);
    }
```

Chart:
[image]

**EDIT**: add some logic to assign colors like this:

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> exception in ExceptionMessages)
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(exception.Key, exception.Value);

            //add business logic for your color here
            if (exception.Key == "Exception 4")
                chart1.Series[0].Points[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - 1].Color = Color.Red;
        }
```

Chart:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this work fin for me, but is there a way I can have each of this exception in different series how I was doing it from before but still have the label under it like the example you showed me, this will give me a chance to find it by color faster in case there is plenty of data in the chart

Comment: You should not add loads of series but give each point a separate color!

Comment: This could be a good solution but as I have no control about the amount of different exception I will get, is there a way to do it dynamically

Comment: Thanks I was able to creating dynamically colors using fromArgb because the exception list is created dynamically and have no information about what could be so I used random to generate RGB colors for each column. Thank you a lot for the help